# Node.js socket.io-client connect_failed / connect_error event

Tags: node.js

I am playing around with node.js and socket.io-client. I am trying to connect to a channel that does not exist in order to trigger the event 'connect_failed' (as specified at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client ).

However I can't get the event working:

```
var clientio = require('socket.io-client');
console.log('Trying stuff ...');

// the channel does not exist
var socket = clientio.connect( 'http://localhost:4000/news' );

// I expect this event to be triggered
socket.on('connect_error', function(){
    console.log('Connection Failed');
});
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('Connected');
});
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('Disconnected');
});
socket.send('hi there');
```

If I execute will this will happen:

```
$ node tmp_clientio.js 
Trying stuff ...
```

Any ideas about how to trigger an error if connecting to a channel that does not exist?

**UPDATE**: Renamed `connect_failed` to `connect_error`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. There is a un-documented difference between namespace mode on and off that I also ran into, in the end I had to use the chrome debugger to work it out.

```
// Bind to the news namespace, also get the underlying socket
var ns_news = clientio.connect( 'http://localhost:4000/news' );
var socket = ns_news.socket
```

So, you see above that you have to get the **actual socket** `ns_news.socket` from your namespace if you want to bind "socket level" events such as connect failed, disconnect, etc

```
// Global events are bound against socket
socket.on('connect_failed', function(){
    console.log('Connection Failed');
});
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('Connected');
});
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('Disconnected');
});


// Your events are bound against your namespace(s)
ns_news.on('myevent', function() {
    // Custom event code here
});
```

Note that you now use ns_news to send or receive events

```
ns_news.send('hi there');
```

Finally, be sure to bind the `socket.on('error', ...)` event as well - it occurs if the port wasn't available

### Full implimentation of 8080 connect with fallback to port 80

I did this in my implementation (try port 8080, if that fails, try port 80 through nginx)

```
socket_port = 8080;

ns_dash = io.connect("http://your.gridspy.co.nz/dash", {
  port: socket_port,
  'connect timeout': 5000,
  'flash policy port': 10843
});

socket = ns_dash.socket;

try_other_port = function() {
  if (socket_port !== 80) {
    if (typeof console !== "undefined" && console !== null) {
      console.log("Trying other port, instead of port " + socket_port + ", attempting port 80");
    }
    socket_port = 80;
    socket.options.port = socket_port;
    socket.options.transports = ['htmlfile', 'xhr-multipart', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'];
    return socket.connect();
  } else {
    return typeof console !== "undefined" && console !== null ? console.log("No other ports to try.") : void 0;
  }
};
socket.on('connect_failed', function() {
  if (typeof console !== "undefined" && console !== null) {
    console.log("Connect failed (port " + socket_port + ")");
  }
  return try_other_port();
});
socket.on('error', function() {
  if (typeof console !== "undefined" && console !== null) {
    console.log("Socket.io reported a generic error");
  }
  return try_other_port();
});
```

I also added an nginx proxy_pass rule, which looks like this

```
location ~ ^/(socket.io)/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

The Upgrade and Connection options here (from more recent versions of nginx) are required to upgrade the connection between nginx and socket.io to support websockets. That means that your webserver can support websockets on port 80.

Furthermore if your server supports ssl / https, this will proxy wss which is the secure version of websockets.

Answer (score 6):

they changed the event name. use

```
reconnect_error
```

or

```
connect_error
```

instead

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L27

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client):

> connect_failed
>
> Fired when the connection timeout occurs after the last connection
>   attempt. This only fires if the connectTimeout option is set. If the
>   tryTransportsOnConnectTimeout option is set, this only fires once all
>   possible transports have been tried.

So this event fires **only if the connectTimeout option is set** (the implementation for that is here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L223-245 ).

So what you should do different in your code is:

```
io.connect('http://localhost:4000/news', { 'connect timeout': 5000 }); 
// set connect timeout to 5 seconds
```

Comment: I misread the documentation. You are right and I have the 'connect timeout' parameter missing in the connect method. However, after amending the code I am having exactly the same result: the event 'connect_failed' is not triggered.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of Socket.IO. If that doesn't work either, you can debug the Socket.IO code by putting in some cosole.log here and there.

Comment: No way to make it working. Updated socket.io-client (not socket.io) and no luck :(

Comment: @Tk421 Did you have any luck? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @giggsey I can make working the clientio but no luck with the event connect_failed :(

Comment: Any news on that? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @giggsey, @Tk421, @coredump, @birkof - please see my answer below. In short `ns_news.socket.on('connect', ...)` works.

Comment: Guys- this is still a problem in the latest version of Socket.io v0.9.x -- see discussion in Github issue: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/652

Answer (score 2):

This applies to version 1.4.5 (might work on previous versions also).

What you want to do is listen for the "error" event on the socket.io client. It will trigger this event, and the error message will be "Invalid namespace".

Here's an example of how to handle it from the socket.io client:

```
  var ioclient = require('socket.io-client');
  var websocket = ioclient('http://myserverurl.com/namespacethatdoesntexist');

  websocket.on('error', function(err){
    if (err == 'Invalid namespace') {
      console.warn("Attempted to connect to invalid namespace");
      //handle the case here...
    } else {
      console.warn("Error on socket.io client", err);
    }
  });
```