# Is there a callback for the io.connect() method in Socket.IO?

Tags: socket.io

Is there any callback for the `io.connect()` method on the client side?  I would like to print some text about connection failure, otherwise proceed normally with the site's socket interactions.

Answer (score 9):

Sure, checkout the documentation for Socket.IO-client with the examples there:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client#sockets-for-the-rest-of-us

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
  // socket connected
});
```

Comment: And if connection is not successfully?

Comment: Check the `connect_failed` event: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client#events

Comment: Seems like on my example this event doesn't fire up :(

Comment: Could this be a firewall issue..? https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software

Comment: Ah btw did you set a connect timeout option? Read this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588689/node-js-socket-io-client-connect-failed-event

Comment: I have set all options and still the reconnect_failed or connect_failed event doesn't trigger :(

Comment: Can you give me more details about your setup and maybe post some code samples?

Comment: Your response is unclear, is that for client side ? Could use some more coding.

Answer (score 4):

In the current release of socket.io (1.3.x) you can use the `connect_error` event or the `reconnect_failed` event:

```
var socket = io(serverUrl);
socket.on('connect_error', function() {
    console.log('Connection failed');
});
socket.on('reconnect_failed', function() {
    console.log('Reconnection failed');
});
```

See: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client#events

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // منو ها
    socket.on('menus', (data, cb) => { 
        controler.menus(data, socket, cb)
    });
});
```

then I use it like this:

```
...
cb(err)
...
```

I hope it helps