# io.connect() is not working and i can't figure what is the problem

Tags: node.js, angularjs, websocket, socket.io

[and this is the angular code [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEJfW.png) [this is my node js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUAOG.png)

Comment: What's the error? Are there any logs?

Comment: @Tushar Shahi: that was basically my question.  We need a good error message ... and I believe the only way to get one is probably for the OP to add error handling to her code.  I gave two examples as to how she might do this.

Comment: @Rosalyna Daichan: Q: did you get a meaningful error message?  This will help us understand the "root cause" ... in order to resolve the actual problem.  Q: Have you resolved the problem?  If so, how?

Comment: @paulsm4 nope i didn't get any error that's why i don't understand what is wrong

Comment: Q: Did you apply either of the "error handling" code snippets in my response below?  And still nothing?  See also: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_error_handling.htm, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651613/421195

Answer (score 1):

1. Please copy/paste your actual code.  Screenshots are discouraged on SO.
2. Be sure to include *ERROR HANDLING* in all of your I/O operations.  For example:

> https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/
>
> ```
> socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
>   if (err.message === "invalid credentials") {
>     socket.auth.token = "efgh";
>     socket.connect();
>   }
> });
> ```

... or ...

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onerror
>
> ```
> webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
>   console.error("WebSocket error observed:", event);
> };
> ```

Your next step is to get a viable error message.

Please review the library's documentation to determine the "best" way to catch and handle errors for your particular application.