# i am using socket.io in node worked for server , but cant connect to my mobile react native as client

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, socket.io

this is my first time to publish my question in stackoverflow.So please correct me if i am wrong and i hope you guys can help me. So i have problem with socket.io-client to implemented in react native. There is no syntax error in my code and can run well in expo. But i cant connect it to my server node js who using socket.io as well. This is my client react native code

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
    import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
         name: 'bob'
      }

      constructor(){
         super();

         this.socket = io('localhost:3000',{jsonp: false});

         console.log('socket = ',this.socket);

         this.socket.on('update', () => this.setState({name: 'Nate'}));
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

And this is my server node js code

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    server.listen(3000);

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log(socket.id);
        socket.on('update', () => {
          console.log('sending update');
          io.emit('update');
        });

        socket.on('sending', () =>{
          console.log('sending');
          io.emit('ending');
        });
    });
```

And this is my index.html code in my server node js

```
    <h1>Hello world </h1>

    <button>Update</button>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        var button = document.querySelector('button');
        button.onclick = function(){
            console.log('update');
            socket.emit('update');
            socket.on('ending',() => {
               console.log('ending');
            });
        }
    </script>
```

This is my expectation result : 
First,  i run my server node js with runnning command line node App.js  and open it on my browser with localhost:3000. 
Second, i run my client react native with command line expo start on my devices.
 
Third, when i click button update on my browser, it will changed text on my devices to Nate. (This is where i failed)

BTW, this is my version app : 
node 8.11.3 
expo 1.1.0-beta.4  
socket.io-client 2.1.1 
react-native-cli 2.0.1 
react-native 0.55.4

And this is my github for my code 
client react native : https://github.com/nyomanyudis/albmus3
server node js : https://github.com/nyomanyudis/serverSocketIO

Comment: What debugging steps have you done?  What errors or log statements have you observed?  Do you know if either of your clients is connecting?  Do you know if your button press is sending the message to the server and it's receiving it?  You need to do some basic debugging and report those results.

Comment: Okay , tq for your quesition . 
1. What debugging steps have you done?
- in my server node js , i try to run in first. before i open localhost:3000 on my browser, console.log(socket.id) is not trigereed. after i open localhost:3000 on my browser, console.log(socket.id) is apperad. So i assumed localhost:3000 on my browser is connected to my server. But if i try  this.socket = io('localhost:3000',{jsonp: false}); on my react native,  console.log(socket.id)  on my server not appeared.
2. What errors or log statements have you observed?
there is no syntax error

Comment: 3.  Do you know if either of your clients is connecting? - In my browser yes it is connected, but no in my react-native. 
4. Do you know if your button press is sending the message to the server and it's receiving it?
Yes , i know.but after it is receiving it and i try to io.emit('update'); in my server , my react native cclient dont recieved that message . maybe it is because it is not conected yet

Comment: OK, it appears your React client isn't connecting and that's where you need to focus your attention.  Does the `console.log('socket = ',this.socket);` show in the react client?

Comment: Yes , it is.  the attribute socket in my browser for connected = true, disconnected = false, and id = hgjgdKjAaZRNP94TAAAC . And in my socket React native client is opposite with id = 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post in an answer (even though we aren't yet to an answer) because I need to post suggested multi-line code for further debugging.  I'd suggest you add this in the React client (note the addition of `http://` to the URL) and all the new event handlers to log other events:

```
let socket = this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000',{jsonp: false});

socket.on('connect_error, function(e) {
    console.log('connect_error', e);
}).on('connect_timeout', , function() {
    console.log('connect_timeout');
}).on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connect');
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('error', e);
}).on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnect');
}).on('reconnect', function(n) {
    console.log('reconnect', n);
}).on('reconnect_error', function(e) {
    console.log('reconnect_error', e);
}).on('reconnect_failed', function(e) {
    console.log('reconnect_failed', e);
});
```

And, then report which of these messages show up in the React client console and what the error messages are.

---

Edit: It sounds like you are getting a message about incompatible versions of client and server.  For socket.io, you should make sure that you have the EXACT same versions of client and server code.

Comment: Okay , after i add it. it is connect_error. but reconnect_error is executed as well.

Comment: @nyomanyudis - OK, I added some more output so you can see the details of the connection errors.  It might be interesting to see what error it's getting when connecting.

Answer (score -1):

this is how i add jfriend00 in my code. just to make sure i dont mistake adding it.

```
this.socket = io('localhost:3000',{jsonp: false});

  let socket = this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000',{jsonp: false});

  socket.on('connect_error', function() {
      console.log('nyoman connect_error');
  }).on('connect_timeout', function() {
      console.log('nyoman connect_timeout');
  }).on('connect', function() {
      console.log('nyoman connect');
  }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('nyoman error', e);
  }).on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('nyoman disconnect');
  }).on('reconnect', function() {
      console.log('nyoman reconnect');
  }).on('reconnect_error', function() {
      console.log('nyoman reconnect_error');
  }).on('reconnect_failed', function() {
      console.log('nyoman reconnect_failed');
  });
```

Comment: You don't need this here.  If you want to show it, you could add it to the end of your question.

Comment: Uhhh, this isn't correct.  You have duplicate `io(...)` lines.  Get rid of the first one.

Comment: ok. i have already delete line this.socket = io('localhost:3000',{jsonp: false}); and it is still same.

Comment: a few minitue ago i found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588689/node-js-socket-io-client-connect-failed-connect-error-event . But i have syntax error with var socket = ns_news.socket because var socket is null.It is confused me because it worked on them, but not worked on me haha.. but it is in node js , not react native

Comment: That does not look correct and is not consistent with the socket.io documentation.  You are already triggering the `connect_error` event so you don't have to do to something else to see that event.  Next step is to see what the error that comes with that event shows.  I modified my suggested code to show that error.

Comment: hmm.. pardon me if i am wrong. but i dont see any difference with your modified suggested code.

Comment: Actually i follow this code from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PyNdOCt6i6Q . it worked on him, but not me. even i follow every step from his instruction.

Comment: I added the error parameters to a number of the errors so the logging will output the error objects that come with them.  We want to see what the `connect_error` error code actually is.

Comment: Oww.. ok. Yeah  the error said Error : xhl poll. So i search it and said i have to downgrade it from 2.1 to 1.7 . But still dont work on me haha.. https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1097

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the exact same socket.io versions on client and server.  Make sure they match exactly.  That will prevent connection.  Don't go by what some search said.  You have to see EXACTLY what version of socket.io you are running on the server and make sure you have that exact same version installed in your React client.

Comment: i have alredy look socket.io-cliet on react native and socket.io on server node js . and it is same 2.1.1

Comment: Then, now what is the exact error message it reports?